# r - rounding in summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to see more digits in the aggregated output using `group_by()` and `summarise()` from package`{dplyr}`. My codes are below:

```
library(dplyr)
# download 2 datasets
download.file('https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FGDP.csv','GDP.csv',mode = 'wb')
GDP<-read.csv('GDP.csv',skip=4,stringsAsFactors = F,na.strings = '')
GDP<-GDP%>%filter(!is.na(X),!is.na(X.1))%>%mutate(X.1=as.numeric(X.1))
download.file('https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FEDSTATS_Country.csv','EDSTATS.csv',mode = 'wb') 
edu<-read.csv('EDSTATS.csv',stringsAsFactors = F)

# join these two datasets
df<-inner_join(GDP,edu,by=c('X'='CountryCode'))%>%arrange(desc(X.1))

# aggregation
df%>%group_by(Income.Group)%>%summarise(avg_GDP=mean(X.1))
```

The result I get from console:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Income.Group         avg_GDP
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 High income: nonOECD    91.9
2 High income: OECD       33.0
3 Low income             134. 
4 Lower middle income    108. 
5 Upper middle income     92.1
```

Clearly, the number were not shown in full. So how do I see more digits in `avg_GDP`?
If I assign the result to a new dataframe and view it in RStudio, I get to see more digits, but still, only 5 digits:

```
df2<-df%>%group_by(Income.Group)%>%summarise(avg_GDP=mean(X.1))
View(df2)
```

So how do I see more digits both in console print and dataframe View()?
I tried:

```
df%>%group_by(Income.Group)%>%summarise(avg_GDP=mean(X.1,digits=10))
```

it didn't work.

My question is different from the potential duplicate is that I want the code that could do the job within the %>% chain. From his post, I like the answer with:

```
# this is my favorite, because it fits well with my original code with %>%.
print.data.frame(my_tbl, digits = 3)
```

or

```
options(digits = 3)
print.data.frame(my_tbl)
```

From my post, I like `options(pillar.sigfig = 10)`.

Comment: Try setting `options(digits = 22)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the tibble package you need to modifiy the option `pillar.sigfig`.

> `pillar.sigfig`: The number of significant digits that will be printed and highlighted, default: 3

```
library(tibble)
options(pillar.sigfig = 10)

set.seed(1)
tibble(a = rnorm(3), b = rexp(3))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#              a            b
#          <dbl>        <dbl>
#1 -0.6264538107 0.4360686258
#2  0.1836433242 2.894968537 
#3 -0.8356286124 1.229562053
```

Comment: I see three numbers are underscored for each row, what does that mean?

Comment: @YangDai *"Groups of three digits are now underlined, starting with the fourth before/after the decimal point. This gives a better idea of the order of magnitude of the numbers."* Click [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/03/pillar-1-2-1/)